# Prevent mounting/initial rendering of a server rendered react component

Tags: reactjs, code-splitting

I'm using a custom tool similar to [react-snap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-snap) to create a snapshot of my app at build time, as [recommended in the create-react-app docs](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#pre-rendering-into-static-html-files). This generates a static server-rendered version, which I can deploy behind nginx without running react on the server. This works fine.

I'm also using code-splitting to lazily load some components to reduce the initial JS payload. (I use react-loadable, but I'm willing to change that if needed.) It works fine when creating the snapshot, and the HTML is generated correctly, which the user receives correctly, and everything is displayed fully server-rendered without even downloading any JS yet. This is great.

However, during rehydration on the client, the `import(...)` call for the async loaded component hasn't yet been fired. Meanwhile, the DOM already has the stuff that has to be rendered, from the snapshot.

In this scenario, is there a way to prevent the initial render of a component during mounting, since I already have the content in the DOM?

Also, is it possible to have react's hydration logic run after the `import` is complete, so that I can prevent any flicker even after the import is complete?

If it matters, the lazy-loaded components are infrequently used routes, managed by react-router.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? I'm facing the same situation as you. :(